# PHP success on file upload

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm sure there is a simple solution that I just can't see.

I have a form for uploading stuff.

When the script completes it uses `Header('Location: admin.php?success')` and a `if($_GET['success']) { echo WOOHOO SUCCESS }` type message before the rest of the script is run.

The problem with this is that is you want to upload 2 files at once you can't because the first part of the script is executed and nothing else.  I then considered using a boolean value to set true or false and display a message from that but that also failed.

I'd like to be able to upload several files in succession and receive a success message for each one.

Many thanks.

relevant PHP:

```
 if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){
        echo '<h2>File Upload Successful! Whoop!</h2>';

    } else{

    if(empty($_POST) === false){

        //check that a file has been uploaded
        if(isset($_FILES['myTrainingFile']) && !empty($_FILES['myTrainingFile']['tmp_name'])){

            file stuff...

            if(in_array($fileExt, $blacklist) === true){
                $errors[] = "File type not allowed";
            }
        }

        if(empty($errors) === true){
            //run update
            move file stuff...
                }

            }

            $comments = htmlentities(trim($_POST['comments']));
            $category = htmlentities(trim($_POST['category']));

            $training->uploadDocument($fileName, $category, $comments);
            header('Location: admin.php?success');
            exit();

        } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
            //header('Location: messageUser.php?msg=' .implode($errors));
            echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';
        }}
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the form on the same page? What is the workflow? Select file, click button, then what happens... can you be more explicit?

Comment: In your "success" message, print_r($_FILES) and make sure they're all being uploaded.  If they are, try something like foreach($_FILES AS $k=>$v){ echo 'File '.$k.' uploaded!<br/>'; }

Comment: @floris - yes the form is on the same page. If it wasn't life might be easier :) 
Workflow from user - select relevant fields, click -Flow from 'site'(?) - check if url is ?success, if so print message, if not chekc form, process upload]

Comment: @dylan - giving it a try now.

Comment: @Dylan - the message prints fine but it still won't allow consecutve uploads due to the logic.  the url is changing to bla.php?success which on the 2nd upload request skips the upload part of the php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the `$_FILES` super-global array and then upload each file.

Here's a working example to give you a better idea.

```
<?php

    $upload_dir= './uploads';
    $num_uploads = 2;
    $max_file_size  = 51200;
    $ini_max = str_replace('M', '', ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    $upload_max = $ini_max * 1024;
    $msg = 'Please select files for uploading';
    $messages = array();

    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
    {
        for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);$i++)
        {
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
            }
            elseif($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > $upload_max)
            {
                $messages[] = "File size exceeds $upload_max php.ini limit";
            }
            elseif($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > $max_file_size)
            {
                $messages[] = "File size exceeds $max_file_size limit";
            }
            else
            {
                if(@copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_dir.'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]))
                {
                    $messages[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i].' uploaded';
                }
                else
                {
                    $messages[] = 'Uploading '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i].' Failed';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Multiple File Upload</title>
 </head>

 <body>

 <h3><?php echo $msg; ?></h3>
 <p>
 <?php
    if(sizeof($messages) != 0)
    {
        foreach($messages as $err)
        {
            echo $err.'<br />';
        }
    }
 ?>
 </p>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size; ?>" />
 <?php
    $num = 0;
    while($num < $num_uploads)
    {
        echo '<div><input name="userfile[]" type="file" /></div>';
        $num++;
    }
 ?>

 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a complete overhaul and looks much better! I can't test until tomorrow now but I'll definitely let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in conjunction with my previous code.  The files always fail to upload.
I also receive and error: Warning: move_uploaded_file(/anythingslider.jquery.json) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Comment: @SteveGreen: That's pretty much self-explanatory. Check the file permissions. Your script should have write-access to the directory. For testing, just set the permission to 777 and see if it works.

Comment: Amal- all sorted now. The permission for folder were always 777. Not ire what the problem was but fixed. Thanks for help

Comment: @SteveGreen: Please accept this answer if it answered your question! :)

Comment: Amal, gladly, I actually had to use a different example instead but I'll happily accept as I think it was more a problem with my structure than the code that you provided:)